# Liferay Build language issue (Automatic copy)

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to **build language** in Liferay. For `Language_en.properties`, it works fine but for other languages it is not translating key value's to respective languages. It only shows english value prefix with **"(Automatic copy)"**.

Any help on this is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay's translation is done via Microsoft Translator. You'll need to sign up for an account on Azure Marketplace and configure it [according to the documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/generating-language-properties-file-and-automated-t). Note that this translation often is only a first step and it will require you to manually correct those translations: Often the typically small snippets don't have enough context for the algorithm to choose the appropriate translation.

Any automatic translation will be flagged as "(Automatic Translation)" (which appears in the properties files, but will not be shown on the UI) - you can use this to manually double-check those entries that have just been automatically translated (when you delete the flag after you've corrected the translation).

Note that [some languages have deliberately been disabled](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.5-ga6/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/tools/LangBuilder.java#L614) from automatic translation, as the algorithm was supposed to have more incorrect, rude, hillarious or offensive translation than one would like to have - for those languages Liferay relies on manual translation even when you have set up an account for automatic translation. You have the option to change those settings, of course, but you'll have to willingly change the code that I'm linking to.

My personal opinion: Don't go with automatic translation - it's rarely correct, more often rude, hillarious or plain wrong.